# What does science say about GM cow research in New Zealand?

Tags: gmo, cows, research

I saw this article while perusing the internet:

http://sustainablepulse.com/2015/10/23/gm-cow-experiments-in-new-zealand-show-disastrous-results/#.VipkId_BzRZ

Looking through the sources, they clearly come from very biased sources but I wasn't able to find a good, skeptical review of these claims. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Unclear what the notable claim is here.

Comment: Please summarise what you think is claimed in the article. Or the question is likely to be closed (we don't like to have to follow links to find out the key claim).